chrome files download directory change in Chrome preferences
Dim chrome As New clsBrowser
Dim addArguments As String

addArguments = "--download.default_directory=""C:\Users\****\Desktop"""
chrome.start cleanActiveSession:=True, userProfile:="User T", addArguments:=addArguments
chrome.navigate "chrome://settings/downloads"

I need your help to change the chrome browser "download directory".
text
text
excel vba file available in this link
selenium basic unusable
It provides remote control to Chrome and Edge browsers.
have to work with excel etca with a javascript decoder
They did it for the convenience of others.
It's a good thing they did it.
Users forgetting to change the Chrome download folder causes malfunctions in the programs I create.
I want to change the download folder with code to prevent this.

Setting --download.default_directory doesn't work?
